# Left Join not returning results when a joni condition fails

Tags: sql, ms-access, null, left-join

After reading a lot about many other people having left join issues and missing rows, I still have not come to a conclusion on why my row is not showing up.

```
SELECT UNIT_MAIN.UNIT_NO
    ,F_CARD.CARD_NO
    ,F_CARD.END_DT
FROM UNIT_MAIN
LEFT JOIN F_CARD
        ON UNIT_MAIN.UNIT_ID = F_CARD.ASSIGNED_ID 
           AND ((F_CARD.CARD_NO)<>'9' & [unit_no]) 
           AND (F_CARD.CARD_NO)<> Replace(LTrim(Replace([unit_no],'0',' ')),' ','0') 
           AND ((F_CARD.END_DT) Is Null))
WHERE UNIT_MAIN.UNIT_NO = '555'
```

'555' is just the value I enter to attempt to find the missing row (I know which row isn't appearing, I can't figure out why). I took out all other where clauses and it still isn't appearing.

I am trying to obtain the `UNIT_NO` in question along with the `F_CARD.CARD_NO` and `F_CARD.END_DT` if applicable. The `F_CARD` table contains two entries that match on `UNIT_ID`, however both do not have a null value in `F_CARD.END_DT`, so the join condition fails.

Does this not mean that the `UNIT_NO` should still appear as the left result of a left join?

The result I would want looks like:

```
555 | null | null
```

But it just doesn't show up. If I remove the `F_CARD.END_DT IS NULL` condition from the join, then I get

```
555 | 123 | Jan 2015
555 | 234 | Feb 2015
```

Thanks!

Comment: Would be very helpful if you could show us what the data in the two tables looks like.  If I understand you, the desired row doesn't have null in the date column?

Comment: Could you display the values for F_CARD.CARD_No and F_CARD.End_date for those records in F_CARD.Assigned_ID = 555? or are they really 123 and 234 with jan 2015 and Feb 2015 respectively?

Comment: Do you mean `is null` or `is not null`? on F_CARD.End_Date?  You have what appear to be contrary statements.  "However both do not have a null value in F-CARD.END_DT " but yet your results in 2nd query show both 123, and 234 have dates... so I'm confused.

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, when you query SELECT UNIT_MAIN.UNIT_NO
FROM UNIT_MAIN
WHERE UNIT_MAIN.UNIT_NO = '555' 
you get a result, right?

Comment: @xQbert If I REMOVE the IS NULL condition, then I would get those results. I don't want those results. I just want 555 | null | null. I don't want the right results returned, hence the join condition. The unit exists for sure. The numbers may differ from my actual table, but the it is just UNIT_NO = '555' and attempting to join F_CARD.CARD_NO = '123' AND F_CARD.END_DT = 11/25/2014,  F_CARD.CARD_NO = '234' AND F_CARD.END_DT = 06/16/2015.

END_DT is to represent if a card is expired, that is why I am looknig for IS NULL on it, so I only join and obtain CARD_NO info when it is not expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I used to deal with this issue was to use subqueries for all join conditions that didn't require matching a column value between two tables.

I don't use MS Access much, but having to deal with the brackets on my joins and this problem involving the join conditions is quite frustrating.